# How to make a video wall?

Tags: networking, multimedia

I want to have a wall of TFT monitors, maybe as many as 10x10, and display a video on the wall.

That means that each monitor should display a part of the video.

Her's a bad ascii art example with only 2x2:

```
_______ _______
|top   ||top   |
|left  ||right |
======= ========
|bottom||bottom| 
|left  ||right |
-------- ------
```

Now, either I find a magic piece of hardware which can control many, many monitors, or I need a separate controller at each monitor.

Which is what I am thinking of:

- A master, Windows based, PC where I process the video, slicing it up.
- I then send each slice to the appropriate micro-controller, one per monitor.
- When ready to play the viedo, I send a command only a few bytes to each MCU, which ought to guarantee that they are in synch.

What do you think? Is there a problem there? Is there a better way?

Comment: And the two down-votes were because ... ?  I really wish the system would force someone to leave a comment when down-voting; at least that would be constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/networksync.html) playing separate videos, presliced from the master.

Comment: +1 This sounds good & might well become the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To do it with consumer hardware, you'll need a computer with several AMD Radeon HD cards (series 5000 or later) in Crossfire. They support Eyefinity which lets you span the desktop across a grid of monitors. For your purposes, you will want to find the versions of th cards that can output to 6 displays from a single card. I think, though, that the maximum number of supported displays is 24, in quad-Crossfire.

The other option is to use Matrox. They make devices that take a regular video signal and split it to multiple displays. I am not as familiar with this setup, but it has been a common one in the professional field for many years. Unfortunately, I don't know how many displays you can output to, maximum, with this method, but you can look into that yourself easily.

Comment: +1 thanks. I will write to tech support of both. I just didn't know where to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/technology/benefits.php) via USB ports.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I will get in touch with their tech support.